# MATLAB: Get small eigenvalues from `eigs` in sorted order

Tags: matlab

For example, `eigs(A,k,'sm')` returns the k smallest magnitude eigenvalues. However, `eigs` does not take care of the sign. Edit: `eigs(A,k,'sr')`takes care of it.

Say `A` is 500 by 500 sparse matrix. Without getting all eigenvalues like in `eig`, how to get the smallest 3 eigenvalues (not magnitude) and the corresponding eigenvectors for `eigs` in a sorted way efficiently?

This can be done easily by getting all eigenvalues in `eig` by sorting but I cannot use `eig` for some reasons as it takes a long time and huge memory to convert to full matrix and compute all eigenvalues.

Edit: This can also be done by `eigs(A,k,'sr')` and do the sorting myself. But is there a faster method or option in `eigs` to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not do that unless there is a syntax error or your matrix has all the eigenvalues with positive real part. This gives the correct negative signed smallest real part (I guess that's what you mean by small) eigenvalues on R2016a. Note that smallest eigs are complex conjugates and one pair is given by only its negative imaginary part.

```
A = sprand(100,100,0.5);
[V,D] = eigs(A,3,'sr')
```

Comment: thanks. `sr` works. Is there any way to output the `D` in a sorted way, without doing sorting myself?